# How to populate matTableDataSource from Observable on first loading

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, mat-table

I am having trouble with populating matTableDataSource on startup. On startup I get empty table with *matNoDataRow message. When I click sort on any column or type anything in filter input, the data appears immediately.

I tried to use hardcoded values for table rows and it works fine. Everything is loaded on startup. I have a working stackblitz example here where I copied everything except subscription, because it gets values from my database:
[StackblitzExampleOfHardcodedArray](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkvgj7-r3utna?file=src/app/table-overview-example.ts)

I also tried to populate array in service and call it in component after (done) but it also did not show the rows.

Here is my original method

```
parseUserData: any;
returnValue: any = [];
getAllBooksFromDatabase() : BooksData[] { //all books from Bookshelf
  this.returnValue.splice(0, this.returnValue.length);
  this.data.getBooks().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.parseUserData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  this.parseUserData.map((item:any) => {
    if(item.fine != 0){
        this.returnValue.push(
          {
            uid: item.uid,
            bid: item.bid,
            bookTitle: item.bookTitle,
            authorLastName: item.authorLastName,
            authorFirstName: item.authorFirstName,
            issuedDate: item.issuedDate,
            period: item.period,
            fine: item.fine,
            warning: item.warning
          }
       );
    }
})
return this.returnValue;
}
```

EDIT: this is my service method for obtaining data

```
public getBooks(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/books')
  .pipe(map((books: any) => books));
}
```

EDIT: and this is part of result - books:

```
    [
  {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "in library",
"period": "0",
"bookTitle": "Balade Petrice Kerempuha",
"bid": "158744286",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Krleža",
"authorFirstName": "Miroslav",
"bookGenre": "poetry",
"uid": ""
  },
  {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "in library",
"period": "0",
"bookTitle": "Na rubu pameti",
"bid": "653621302",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Krleža",
"authorFirstName": "Miroslav",
"bookGenre": "poetry",
"uid": ""
 },
 {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "in library",
"period": null,
"bookTitle": "Kule u zraku",
"bid": "746388428",
"fine": null,
"authorLastName": "Larsson",
"authorFirstName": "Stieg",
"bookGenre": "triler",
"uid": null
 },
 {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "borrowed",
"period": "1",
"bookTitle": "U zemlji klanova",
"bid": "542455118",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Rudan",
"authorFirstName": "Igor",
"bookGenre": "popularization of science",
"uid": "0231027834"
 },
 {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "borrowed",
"period": "1",
"bookTitle": "Točna boja neba",
"bid": "542455578",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Rudan",
"authorFirstName": "Igor",
"bookGenre": "popularization of science",
"uid": "0231027834"
 },
 {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "in library",
"period": "0",
"bookTitle": "Očekujući vatre",
"bid": "548754578",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Rudan",
"authorFirstName": "Igor",
"bookGenre": "popularization of science",
"uid": ""
 },
 {
"warning": "",
"issuedDate": "in library",
"period": "0",
"bookTitle": "Zao zrak",
"bid": "548755578",
"fine": "0",
"authorLastName": "Rudan",
"authorFirstName": "Igor",
"bookGenre": "popularization of science",
"uid": ""
 }
 ]
```

How can I show all table rows on startup?
Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show how you're obtaining the values from the backend. **Not** the actual data, but how you are trying to obtain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.returnValue` variable is assigned asynchronously. So by the time you're returning it, it's still empty. You could instead modify your data using RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator along with Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions and assign it directly in the `ngOnInit` hook.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllBooksFromDatabase().subscribe(
    books => {
      this.dataSourceBook = new MatTableDataSource(books);
      this.dataSourceBook.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSourceBook.sort = this.sort;
    }
  );
}

getAllBooksFromDatabase(): Observable<BooksData[]> { // all books from Bookshelf
  return this.data.getBooks().pipe(
    map(data => {
      return data
        .filter(item => item.fine != 0)        // <-- your condition
        .map(item => {
          return {
            uid: item.uid,
            bid: item.bid,
            bookTitle: item.bookTitle,
            authorLastName: item.authorLastName,
            authorFirstName: item.authorFirstName,
            issuedDate: item.issuedDate,
            period: item.period,
            fine: item.fine,
            warning: item.warning
          }
        })
      })
  );
}
```

More info on async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data
      .getBooks()
      .pipe(
        filter((data) => !!data),
        map((data: any[]) => {
          data.map((item: any) => {
            if (item.fine != 0) {
              return {
                uid: item.uid,
                bid: item.bid,
                bookTitle: item.bookTitle,
                authorLastName: item.authorLastName,
                authorFirstName: item.authorFirstName,
                issuedDate: item.issuedDate,
                period: item.period,
                fine: item.fine,
                warning: item.warning,
              };
            }
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((books: BooksData) => {
        this.dataSourceBook = new MatTableDataSource(books);
        this.dataSourceBook.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSourceBook.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }
```